# InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```cs
DBL_APP_USER user = _db.DBL_APP_USER.SingleOrDefault(
    a => a.UserID == login.UserID && a.Password == login.Password && a.IsActive == true
);
```

This code was working fine with `VS 2019 (i.e. .Net Core 5)`, but after I upgrade to `VS 2022 (.Net Core 7)` its giving error. Also there is no duplicate record for given condition in database, becuase UserID is a primary key column.

Comment: Try `_db.DBL_APP_USER.Where(a => a.UserID == login.UserID && a.Password == login.Password && a.IsActive == true).ToList()` and examine returned records.

Comment: Its already tried, that also giving same error, but now after upgrading Nuget EF 5 to EF 7 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading NuGet Package EF 5 to EF 7, issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
_db.DBL_APP_USER.Where(a => a.UserID == login.UserID && a.Password == login.Password && a.IsActive == true).FirstorDefault()
```